# How to launch a service like mysql in a docker container?

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker, docker-compose, archlinux

So I've tried to create a `docker-compose.yml` file to create one container for my web app with laravel and an other container for my database with mariadb. I've tried to link those two container together so that laravel could fetch data from mariadb. The problem is that my laravel container does not have a mysql socket file, so it can't use mysql. I'm pretty sure that I've missed something, or that I don't understood something because nothing works. So my question is **how do we propely connect a archlinux container with laravel to a mysql container?** Here's my docker-compose file

```
version: '3'
services:
database:
  build: ./database
  container_name: database.dev
  command: mysqld --user=root --verbose
  ports:
    - "3307:3306"
  restart: always
 web:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - "/app"
    ports:
     -  "8000:8000"
    links:
      - database
    depends_on:
      - database
```

When I'm trying to install mysql in my archlinux container, mysql won't create a service at `/etc/init.d/mysql` or event a socket file at `/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`. I get this output when I try to use mysql in my container terminal.

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")
```

Here are my docker files:

**database/Dockerfile**

```
FROM mysql:latest

RUN mkdir -p /db
WORKDIR /db

COPY . /db

RUN cd /db
RUN /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM base/archlinux

RUN mkdir -p /app

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

RUN pacman -Syu --noconfirm
RUN pacman -S openssh composer php mariadb --noconfirm

RUN groupadd -g 89 mysql &>/dev/null
RUN useradd -u 89 -g mysql -d /var/lib/mysql -s /bin/false mysql &>/dev/null
#RUN chown -R mysql:mysql var/lib/mysql &>/dev/null

RUN mysql_install_db --user=mysql --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql
RUN COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1
RUN cd /app 
RUN /usr/bin/composer install 
RUN echo APP_KEY= > .env 
RUN echo DB_USERNAME=root >> .env 
RUN echo DB_PASSWORD= >> .env 
RUN cat php.ini > /etc/php/php.ini #my custom configuration for the project
RUN php artisan key:generate 
RUN ln -srf storage/app/public public/storage
RUN php artisan storage:link


VOLUME ["/app"]

EXPOSE 8000

CMD php /app/artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000
```

I don't feel like I'm doing the proper thing, anyone can help me or show me the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [repository](https://github.com/greyltc/docker-LAMP/pull/16) on GitHub is an ArchLinux based image for docker, it includes PHP, PHP-composer, MySQL, PostgreSQL, and MariaDB. I just had to tweak it a bit to make it work and suits my needs!